# How to include multiple urls.py from the same django app?

Tags: django, django-urls, htmx

I'm new to django and htmx and was trying to keep my urls.py a bit more clean by putting all urls which just give a htmx response into another file.
To include this file into my paths I used djangos include function, because I'd like to route all htmx-specific request over an url called /htmxFunctions/*
The folder structur is:

project

- base_project

  - urls.py
- my_app

  - urls.py
  - htmx

    - htmx_urls.py

my url files look like this:

```py
# base_project/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("my_app.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("__reload__/", include("django_browser_reload.urls")), #tailwind specific
]
```

```py
#my_app/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
     ...
    # htmx-funktionen
    path("htmxFunctions", include("my_app.htmx.htmx_urls")),
]
```

```py
my_app/htmx/htmx_urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("test", views.test, name="test"),
    path("", views.index, name="test"), # for testing purposes
]
```

My Problem is, using `hx-post="/htmxFunctions/test/"` only results in an 404 error. but the general include seems to work because just using `hx-post="/htmxFunctions"` gives the right response.
Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Allready checked for spelling errors, tried porbably every combination of using slashes in the routes of hx-post and my path but nothing seems to work. Also tried namespacing but didn't really get what it is supposed to do.

```py
 path(
        "htmxFunctions",
        include(("my_app.htmx.htmx_urls", "htmx"), namespace="htmx"),
    ),
```

Comment: am not sure, but are you missing the `/` on purpose ? in general case, you are trying to reach `/htmxFunctionstest/` as you did not added `/` to the end of url

Comment: @George THANK YOU! This was the problem! I got this Error: `RuntimeError: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set.` and deleted the slash but, I just had to add it in my htmx too... Thank you very much for the fast help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to George I found my problem! My django path didn't end with a slash (I only used include with an empty string before and all my other paths we're endpoints so they didn't needed one. I forgot about it).

```py
...
# htmx-funktionen
    path("htmxFunctions/", include("my_app.htmx.htmx_urls")) 
...
```

Now it works :)

Comment: you can mark this answer as accepted now. glad I helped.

Comment: Stack overflow lets my mark this as accepted in two days because it's my own answer:D But I will do it :)